# Extract multiple values with JSON extractor

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm getting following data in response of a request:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 54925,
      "currCode": "USD",
      "lastUpdated": 1531233169000
    },
    {
      "id": 54926,
      "currCode": "USD",
      "lastUpdated": 1531233169000
    },
    {
      "id": 54927,
      "currCode": "USD",
      "lastUpdated": 1531233169000
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 3
}
```

As we can see there are three different ids in the data(54925,54926,54927)
I want to perform iterate over all these ids and perform some operation( basically I want to use like `foreach(String id: ids) { request(id);}`

I added a JSON extractor as follows:

[image]
As per my research([research link](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/extract-json-content-efficiently-with-jmeter-using-json-path-syntax-with-ubik-load-pack/)) it's supposed to store all the ids in the `id_list`

After this added a foreach loop to iterate over these values:

[image]

But somehow the it's not going inside this for loop. What I'm doing wrong here?
is there any other way to fetch all these ids and  loop through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to mention in [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) you expect it to return all values by setting `Match No.` as `-1`

> -1 means extract all results, they will be named as _N